# How can I fix NUnit tests that succeed locally, but fails in Jenkins?

Tags: docker, unit-testing, jenkins, .net-core, nunit

I have a unit test that is succeeding locally in Visual Studio and on the command line, but it is failing when Jenkins builds the [pull request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_version_control#Pull_requests).

There are 29 tests in total, but only one is failing and I cannot find a reason why this is happening.

The method to test is this:

```
RuleFor(url => url).Must(url => Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.Absolute, out Uri uriResult))
                .OnFailure((url) => throw new CustomException($"The URL {url} provided is not a valid URL"));
```

The unit test: `Assert.Throws<CustomException>(() => _sut.Validate("/image.png"));`

The error: `Expected CustomException but found null`

I am running [.NET Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Core) 3.1 on Windows and the tests in Jenkins are running in [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29).

It seems like the issue is that it succeeds only on Windows. I tried on Mac, but it fails :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that locally was working fine because I was on WINDOWS.
On the other side, Docker was running a LINUX container, so it recognized the string as an absolute LOCAL PATH. Since Uri also supports paths the test failed there. It failed on Mac OS for the same reason.

I ended up changing the unit test and added an extra check.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've had a similar issue to yours and it was down to the order the tests were being run to why it's succeeding locally.

Make sure your tests don't depend on others in any way.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a Jenkins issue. I think it's a test case issue.

The code `_sut.validate` is able to generate the URI correct.

I assume Jenkins is internally converting the URL provided for each container (micro-service) and resolving the name correctly. The system under test is working fine and creating the URL successfully.

Please change your input URL and your application will start throwing error.